# How to open a link in a new tab in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to open all links in Wordpress in a new tab? I am using a Child Theme of Sydney wordpress. I do not know coding. Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  What is the exact sequence of events that you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your `/index.php` file and pop [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp) within the `<head>` tag.

```
<base target="_blank">
```

*P.S. If your not able to do this. It might be best to do at-least a tiny bit of research about web code and Wordpress.*

Comment: Thanks X-Ray Specs!

Comment: I am using a Child Theme. The Child Theme when clicked has a functions.php and no index.php. Both are same?

Comment: To Edit this Functions.php, I have created a 'site specific plugin, the code reads as under "<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for chennairealties.in
Description: Site specific code changes for chennairealties.in
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */" This plugin was created on the instructions of a web tutorial by WP Beginner. This is working fine. I have pasted some codes in this..2)When I click the Themes in Cpanel, all the Themes are showing along with the index.php file which reads like this"<?php
// Silence is golden." Please tell me where to paste the code?

Comment: This also makes internal links to open in new tab. So not exact answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu items open in new tabs then there is an option for that in menu options. please see below images

[tick link target option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkVWp.png)

[open link in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMgsK.png)

If you want all external links open in new tabs , then

I tried a few plugins for this, and “Open external links in a new window” was my favorite.Search it in plugin page, install it. It will work well. :)

Comment: Thanks Ashkar. I want all posts/page/image/and internal links to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

**without jQuery**

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Comment: Thanks purvik 7373

Comment: Where is <head>   </head> in a child theme? Can I use the plugin 'insert header and footer'?Thanks

Comment: @JMDas yes, you can add between `<head></head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks Purvik. I added the tag <base target="_blank"> to the Plugin. Now it works. All the links open in new tabs.

Comment: @JMDas Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.